# how to include a URL in a customized way with unsrt?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

While there are several mentions along these lines, I haven't been able to solve this completely. (I am including an MWE below that compiles but doesn't do what I want.) I prefer to do it with unsrt.

I am trying to include the URL in the list of references, in a customized way. Ideally, I would be able to write some marco or define how I want the URL to be displayed. Right now I can't get it to display at all.

For example, if I could define a command such as

```
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{Here is the URL: \url{#1}}
```

and then use \myref to display the URLs in the reference list (in the end of each reference), that would be ideal.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{paper-22}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{x}


\end{document}
```

x.bib:

```
@proceedings{paper-22,
    title = "Proceedings of Conference",
    year = "2022",
    publisher = "A Publisher",
    url = "https://myurl",
}
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your bibtex style doesn't exactly do what you want, it might be worth switching to biblatex. This is much more flexible and easier to customise and changing the url field to include your desired text wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `unsrt` bibliography style is really old -- so old, in fact, that it pre-dates the creation of the world wide web and hence the notion of `URL` strings. I suggest you switch to the `unsrtnat` bibliography style and start using the `natbib` citation management package so that you can start working with the `url` field.

Comment: @Mico ok, this was definitely the most useful, eye-opening advice I received this week so far. I switched to unsrtnat and with a bit of more tinkering got it to work. I will include an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the `unsrt` bibliography style belongs to a time where the world was a better place. Here is a fix that does what's expected with a field named `url`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

%% Either load 'natbib' with suitable options or execute
%% a suitably-specified '\setcitestyle' instruction:
\usepackage[round, numbers, sort]{natbib}
%%\setcitestyle{square,numbers,comma}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

\cite{paper-22}    
\bibliography{x}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code so that it's internally consistent. E.g., specifying `authoryear` after `numbers` has no effect at all. Feel free to revert.